# Is it possible to view the "source" for a ksh function?

Tags: linux, unix, function, ksh

Our ksh environment defines several functions.  The names of these functions can be listed using then `typeset -f` ksh command (or the `functions` alias).  Is it possible to see the definition (ie source code) for these functions?

This seems like an obvious question, but I've tried all manner of parameters to `typeset -f` with no luck.

As an example (on Linux):

```
$ foo()
> {
>  echo foo
> }
$ foo
foo
$ typeset -f foo
foo
$
```

For some (but not all) other functions defined by default in the environment, `typeset -f` *does* show the source.

Update 1: This is happening with Linux kernel 2.4.21-32

Update 2: Update 2: Ctrl-V gives "Version M 1993-12-28 n+" - seems like this is quite an old version so might not have the fixes mentionned by Gilles below

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: `functions` will list the source, at least i tried on my version of ksh

Comment: It seems that on Linux, the "functions" command shows the source for some functions but not all. On Solaris it only shows a list of the function names.

Comment: And the version of ksh? Might as well include the distribution and its version, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question doesn't mention the version of ksh but suggests an older version which may have a bug or limitation. Here are relevant extracts from the ksh93 changelog:

> 08-01-31  --- Release ksh93s+  ---
>   07-11-01  A bug in which typeset -f fun did not display the function definition
>             when invoked in a subshell has been fixed.
>
> 03-03-18  --- Release ksh93o  ---
>   03-02-28  All function definitions can be displayed with typeset -f not
>             just those stored in the history file.  In addition, typeset +f
>             displays the function name followed by a comment containing the
>             line number and the path name for the file that defined this function.

Answer (score 6):

To see the source of a given function, use `typeset -f <function-name>`, for example:

```
$ foo
foo
$ typeset -f foo
function foo
{
    echo foo
}
```

You can also use a bare `typeset -f` to see all functions and their source.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't realised that `functions` was just an alias to `typeset -f` - I've updated the question above.

Comment: That is an odd one.  What version of linux & ksh?  Do the functions that don't display have anything in common?